# Node.js remote interpreter

Tags: node.js, jetbrains-ide

I use a Node.js remote interpreter in JetBrains products.
How can I make sure node_modules etc. are not copied over to my remote every time I run my code using the remote interpreter run configuration?

Is it possible to only transfer a typescript "build" product and not all node_modules etc.?